# Deserialize a list of string elements w/ simple-and and retrofit on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

I am using the simple-xml library (https://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) to deserialize a list of string elements.

```
<Parent>
  <PropertyList>
    <Entry>image/png</Entry>
    <Entry>application/atom+xml</Entry>
    <Entry>application/json;type=utfgrid</Entry>
```

Which I successfully deserialize with:

```
data class PropertyList(
   @field:ElementList(name = "Entry", inline = true)
   var entries: List<Entry> = mutableListOf()
)

@Root(name = "Entry", strict = false)
class Entry(
   @field:Text
   var entry: String? = null
)
```

However I am trying to figure out if I can remove the extra Entry class and just deserialize into a list of Strings:

```
data class PropertyList(
   @field:ElementList(name = "Entry", inline = true)
   var entries: List<String> = mutableListOf()
)
```

When I try that I end up with an empty list.  Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried: `@field:ElementList(name="Entry", entry="Entry", inline=true, required=false, type=String::class)`

Comment: I tried that minus the "entry" property, seems as if that is the key.  @RAI go ahead and add that as an answer so I can reward the bounty.

Comment: thank you, but due to the moderator my answer was deleted for no reason and wasn't restored after the investigation

Answer (score 1):

you can annotate the entries field in your PropertyList class with @field:ElementList(inline = true, entry = "Entry", required = false), like this:

```
data class PropertyList(
    @field:ElementList(inline = true, entry = "Entry", required = false)
    var entries: List<String> = mutableListOf()
)
```